# Ajax enabled WCF service not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, iis

I have been working on Ajax enabled WCF service for sometime now, but never with windows authentication. It works fine when running straight from the VS 2010 but when deployed to a web server, it throws errors.

This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GISAlloc.Services.GISServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GISAlloc.Services.GISServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="GISAlloc.Services.GISService" behaviorConfiguration="GISAlloc.Services.GISServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GISAlloc.Services.GISService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

but when I try to get the data, from asp.net, i get error 500 and this is from my windows logs:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/51925686 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/Services/GISService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception
>   during compilation.  The exception message is: The extended protection
>   settings configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the
>   transport.  The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do
>   not match.  IIS has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport
>   has a value of Never.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The extended
>   protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings
>   configured on the transport.  The
>   ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  IIS
>   has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport has a value of
>   Never.

and this is the code from my script:

```
var navService = new GISAlloc.GISService();
navService.GetGISList(shownav, null, null);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have made some updates in the IIS and now i can view the service but when calling it from the javascript i now get another error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: can you post your service code and javascript call?

Comment: I did more fiddling around and converted the svc to asmx, all OperationContracts were changed to webmethods and also enabled [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] and it just worked. I had to change the javascript to GISAlloc.Services.GISService.GetGISList(shownav, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a binding for Ajax. The example below supports Json/Xml/and Plain XML

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebxmlHttp">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WebjsonHttp">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureServiceBehavior" name="xxxx.Web.Services.Reporting.ServiceImplementation.Ixxxx">
        <clear/>
        <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebxmlHttp" behaviorConfiguration="xmlBehavior" name="webXMLHttpBinding" contract="xxxx.Web.Services.Reporting.ServiceContracts.Ixxxx"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebjsonHttp" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" name="webJSONHttpBinding" contract="xxxx.Web.Services.Reporting.ServiceContracts.Ixxxx"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="xmlBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:03:00"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="10"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--Need aspNet compatibility here to get at the HttpRequest. This is a true shortcut to getting the requests original URL prior to being 
    passed of to the wcf protocols. The "original" http reuest uri is used in the HMACMD5 Authentication 
    This ensures that the ASP.NET pipeline is fired up and configured for every incoming request
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    -->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

With this configuration applied your functions could be called with these options:

```
https://MyService.svc/<json|xml|pox>/SomeEntity/SomeID
```